# HAproxy as a reverse proxy - no load balancing

Tags: centos, reverse-proxy, haproxy, squid

I want to configure HA Proxy to act only as a reverse proxy it's being implemented to replace Squid.

At the moment I have it working, where a request comes to the physical firewall on port 80, that firewall passes it through to the HA proxy server which then passes it on to the backend webserver on a different port.

This is the simple config I'm using;

```
 listen test 10.10.250.20:80
        mode tcp
        balance roundrobin
        option tcplog
        server static test.com.webserver:9081  check
```

This is fine when there is only one webserver & website but I want to configure it in a way that the HA proxy listens for traffic coming in on a domain name like test.com & then redirects the traffic & not the IP address of the Ha proxy server which is 10.10.250.20.

Is that possible?

Comment: Is https://serverfault.com/questions/788132/how-to-configure-haproxy-as-a-reverse-proxy what you want?

Comment: Do not remove my edit to make your post readable. See https://serverfault.com/editing-help